# Xcode 5 readonly properties require instance variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, readonly, xcode5

Apologies about the title of this question; it is always hard to sum up these things into a few words.

I've noticed in Xcode 5 that if I create a `@property` as `readonly` I get compiler errors on my references to the instance variable in my code. For example :

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIView *aView;
```

Then in my implementation somewhere :

```
self.anotherView = _aView; // blah blah
```

The instance variable is automatically created for me (I thought), so why do I get `unknown type` errors for readonly properties? I'm sure it didn't do this before.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed any difference in Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 regarding properties semantics.

Is it possible that that you defined an accessor `aView` somewhere, leading Xcode to believe that there is no need for an instance variable?

Comment: No. Nothing out of the ordinary. To be honest I am spotting weird behaviour in general from Xcode 5 - compiler errors show up but it still builds etc; but the above issue is preventing a build. I'm hoping a patch will fix this.